# why two config.xml files in phonegap 3.1.0

Tags: plugins, cordova, command-line-interface

With the latest version of phonegap 3.1.0,
I tried created phonegap project with android platform using CLI command: phonegap build android. 2 config.xml files are created.

1) under folder res > xml
2) under folder assets > www

Whenever I add in a plugin through CLI, config.xml under res > xml folder gets updated. The other is left outdated. I wish to know which of these two files is phonegap really referring to. Any explanation for this? Thanks

I cannot attach any pics here cos I dun have 10 reputation as of now. Let me know if you need to see any pictures for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The one under the assets/www is accidentally copied because of the way CLI copies the www folder. You can ignore it

Comment: I experimented with this, by deleting the config.xml under www. Run the program through ADT eclipse to my hp which has api 18. It worked. Then I ran the program on my colleague hp whose api is 10 and it didnt work. Is this behaviour expected? The program does a simple ajax calling. In config.xml, for access, we placed '*'.

Comment: You should target the latest API level. Officially cordova supports the latest only. In my experience it will not compile for API levels smaller than 13

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that it.

Did you use Phonegap Build? If you use Phonegap Build, you will need file config.xml in www folder to Phonegap Build auto build your project to apk, ipa,... And If you want to build app myselt, you will need file config.xml under res/xml/config.xml.

Comment: Another behaviour observed was adding of plugin feature tags. When I use CLI to add plugins (eg. device), the additional tags are updated on config.xml under res > xml folder and not the one under www. Since this is phonegap project and most would use phonegap build for multi-platform, why isn't phonegap updating the config.xml file under www?

Comment: Exactly. when you add plugin by CLI then it not update config.xml file under www. Phonegap Build not use your plugin added. Phonegap Build have another way to add plugin into project [here](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins-using)